# How to pass a 2 dimensional array as a function argument in Go?

Tags: arrays, go

So I want to be able to pass a matrix as a function in an argument in Golang.  It could be a different size each time - e.g., a 4x4 matrix, 3x2 matrix, etc.  If I try running the test code below against the source code I get an error message like:

How do I pass a 2 dimensional array into a function?  I'm new to Go and come from a dynamic language background (Python, Ruby).

```
cannot use mat[:][:] (type [][3]int) as type [][]int in argument to zeroReplaceMatrix
```

**source code**

```
func ReplaceMatrix(mat [][]int, rows, cols, a, b int) {

}
```

**test code**

```
func TestReplaceMatrix(t *testing.T) {
    var mat [3][3]int
    //some code
    got := ReplaceMatrix(mat[:][:], 3, 3, 0, 1)
}
```

Comment: arrays, I need to read up on slices....though the core problem is being able to use an array like data structure and passing that as an argument

Comment: in this case the slice fit better. Since the array has a limitation: its length must be non-negative constant.

Comment: FYI, your slice syntax doesn't do what you think it does. The `mat[:]` slices the outer array creating a `[][3]int`. Adding another slice operator just repeats the process -- `mat[:][:][:]` is still a `[][3]int`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way to use slices. Unlike arrays they are passed by reference,not by value. For example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Matrix [][]float64
func main() {
    oneMatrix := Matrix{{1, 2}, {2, 3}}
    twoMatrix := Matrix{{1, 2,3}, {2, 3,4}, {5, 6,7}}
    print (oneMatrix)
    print (twoMatrix)

}
func print(X Matrix) {
    for _, i := range X {
        for _, j := range i {
            fmt.Printf("%f ", j)
        }
        fmt.Println()
    }
}
```

[link:](https://play.golang.org/p/UV_0HcOwsE)